# Joining meshes makes weird things

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, modifiers

I'm working on these trees and when I join the the two parts the do this:
[image]
[image]
Does someone knows why this happen or how to solve it?
Meshes haven't modifiers at all.

EDIT: I have noted, When I join the meshes it became a mesh with two materials. And faound this same problem when using more than one material in a mesh in other case.

Video SHowing the issue:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vkm1s97pM9xOuRF5J981CwfwyxQT-GTd

Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't upload photos taken with a smartphone camera. Every operation system in existence is capable of taking screenshots for at least 25 years now. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: I posted from my celphone because pc´s modem is not working.